# How would I allow a CheckBox to show more options after being checked on Android Studio?

Tags: android, checkbox, click

I currently have two CheckBox where if one is checked the other cannot be checked. I would like to be able to check one box, and the other CheckBox option would move towards the bottom of the screen to create space. How would I do this? Also, after it has created space, I would like to show more CheckBox options for each of the original CheckBoxes, how would I add these, and keep them hidden until the checkbox is clicked. Also, it would reverse if the checkbox is unchecked.

Essentially, I want to be able to click a checkbox, and have more checkbox options appear underneath.

This is my current code for the checkboxes:

```
final CheckBox chk1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
final CheckBox chk2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

chk1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        chk2.setChecked(false);
        chk1.setChecked(b);
        chk2.setAlpha(0.5f);
        chk1.setAlpha(1f);
    }
});

chk2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        chk1.setChecked(false);
        chk2.setChecked(b);
        chk1.setAlpha(0.5f);
        chk2.setAlpha(1f);
    }
});
```

Comment: You could create a separate layout in xml that becomes 'visible' when the checkbox is checked and 'gone' when the checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RadioGroup` for `CheckBox` and implement `RadioGroup` method like below, so check box check easy for you.

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    switch(checkedId){
        case R.id.radioCredit:
            CHECK_RADIO="credit";
            break;
        case R.id.radioDebit:
            CHECK_RADIO="debit";
            break;
    }
}
```

Under this implement method you do your work better